# change UITextview placeholder

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextview

I am trying to change the placeholder text of a [RSKGrowingTextview](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKGrowingTextView/blob/master/RSKGrowingTextView/RSKGrowingTextView.swift) after it becomes the first responder and the cursor is in the textview, but no text has yet to be typed.

Basically, it starts as a textview with the label of something like "Post your comment"

And when the user selects the textview to type something and the keyboard pops up, it should say something like "Type your comment".

I attempted to do something like:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    textView.placeholderText = "Type your comment" //This does not
    self.commentTextView.placeholderText = "Type your comment" //This does not
    self.postButton.alpha = 1.0 //This works but is also unrelated

    return true
}
```

Comment: Well if you only want to have a place holder, using a plain text view and label will be sufficient to achieve all these

Comment: @FangmingNing I also need the growing functionality of the RSKGrowingTextView, hence why I am using it in the first place.  Otherwise, yeah.  The RSKGrowingTextView is a child of the RSKPlaceholderTextview which is basically just a textview with a label